# IE7 unable to offset with a margin

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Would anyone be able to tell me why my following code doesn't centre the "block" on the "pivot" in IE7?

Instead it seems to half the size of the "block" for those browsers.

```
<style>
.pivot {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
}
.block {
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;

   margin-left: -50%;
   margin-top: -50%;

   background-color: green;
}
</style>

<div class="pivot">
<div class="block"></div>
</div> <!-- end pivot -->
```

**EDIT**

To get this to work I used Erics code for IE6-IE-7 hacked into my margin approach for all other browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the done thing is to use relative positioning:

```
<style>
.pivot {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
}
.block {
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;

   position: relative;
   left: -50%;
   top: -50%;

   background-color: green;
}
</style>

<div class="pivot">
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eric, 1 thing tho.. its no longer vertically centred in Chrome, Opera etc. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @THomas: Not a clue. You can fix it by specifying a height on the container, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Something in your code is wrong, try giving to pivot width and height and it wont work in any browser.

If you want to center an element in the center of the screen you should do something like that:

```
#element {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -100px;
margin-top: -100px;
background-color: green;
}
```

And it will work in all browsers, including IE6-7.

Comment: Alon, in your example why does it not work if you use margin-left:-50% and margin-top:-50% in IE7?

Comment: Because its already has a left property with 50% value, the trick is  to give a negative margin for the half of it's width.

Comment: Alon, I see what you mean now. This solution works, but I want the margin to to automatically centre without specificing pixel value. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

Is this not an option for you?

```
.pivot {
    text-align: center;
}
.block {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: No, that wasn't exactly what I was after :)